# How do I tell `man` to use `batcat` to view man pages?

Tags: command-line, manpage

I would like to use `batcat` (or `bat` for short) to view man pages, because `batcat` will implement syntax highlighting with different colours.

I've installed `batcat` like this:

```
sudo apt install bat
```

I would like this to work on different shells, including Bash, Zsh, and Fish.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines to your `.bashrc` file in your home directory:

```
export MANPAGER="sh -c 'col -bx | batcat -l man -p'"
export MANROFFOPT="-c"
```

(If you're using a shell other than Bash, then add those lines to the appropriate configuration file for that shell)

This works quite well for most man pages:

```
man bat
```

[image: Screenshot]

You might be wondering, why not use this simpler configuration instead?

```
 export MANPAGER='batcat -l man -p' # does not work
```

I've found it that this simpler configuration doesn't always work. Sometimes, the colour codes that look like `[0m22m` don't get interpreted correctly, causing display issues and search issues. Try `man git-diff` to see an example of where this simpler configuration fails to work.